# If statement based on onclicks in javascripts

Tags: javascript

I am working with a function that changes an image in the browser when you click somewhere in the window. I'd like to make an alert message pop after a certain number of clicks. I thought you would just set the window.onclick function to a variable, and make an if statement inside it checking to see if the clicks are more then the length in the imageArray. Am I supposed to set the onlick function to a number so it can be compared properly? Thanks!

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");

var imageArray = [
  "_images/hurley.png", "_images/lopate.png", "_images/pat.png",
  "_images/saveaya_b.png", "_images/saveaya.png", "_images/stanely.png"
]

var imageIndex = 0;

function changeImage(){
  myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
  imageIndex++;
  if(imageIndex >= imageArray.length){
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
}

var a = window.onclick = function(){
    changeImage();
    if (a >=  imageArray.length[3]){
        alert("you clicked me!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `a` variable is superfluous and wrong. You are already checking the `imageindex` in the `changeImage` function, and I have no idea why you're trying to compare it to the third index of a number...

Just add your alert to the `if` block that sets `imageIndex` to zero.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Funny, I debated whether to include a preamble to my level of experience with the language, but I figured why bother with that? I though folks on here would appreciate people who are obviously new to the language but are giving it a go....cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your if statement in your `.onclick` method to this:

```
if (imageIndex > imageArray.length) {
    alert("you clicked me!");
}
```

The `a` variable is wrongly declared and used. There's no reason you should have it in the first place if your intent is to compare the clicks with the array length. Your inital `imageArray.length[3]` is incorrect as well. `x.length` returns the number of elements in`x` if `x` is an array.